# Looking for the title of a movie I saw years ago. There was personal ports on hand

Tags: story-identification

Everyone has his own port on his hand. Ports was kind of living thing, soft and reshapable. I have only a view in my memory. The idea was awesome. I would like to see the full movie.

Comment: what were the ports for?  Virtual reality?  Was a 'game' involved?

Comment: I don't remember exactly. @john-o must be right. That was the picture on my memory. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07WGSV0h3lU)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possibly Cronenberg's [eXistenZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existenz). However, the "biological" ports in that film were in the spine, I believe.

Comment: Hilarious ending

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks. Do you know another movie contains something like that (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07WGSV0h3lU)

Comment: @Can It's a weird movie, it's Cronenberg after all. I don't know of any others quite like it, especially in that aspect. Of course the late 1990s saw a bunch of virtual reality movies, so anything's possible.