# Virtual reality TV movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a TV movie where a person gets plugged in using an organic cord in their back to explore a virtual world

Comment: What kind of virtual world was it? Was the person a lady-person or a man-person? When did you watch it?

Comment: It is most definitely *eXistenZ*. It is a Canadian film from the late 90s (not a TV movie, but perhaps you saw it on the television) by "body horror" director David Cronenberg. It stars Jude Law, Jennifer Jason Leigh, Willem Defoe, and Ian Holm.  (I like it.)

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31182/looking-for-the-title-of-a-movie-i-saw-years-ago-there-was-personal-ports-on-ha

Answer (score 10):

The use of an "organic cord" reminds me of *[eXistenZ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120907/)*.

You can see the connecting cables [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxZJkjG5elY) at timestamp 39:09

[image]

Comment: Given that this movie was released within weeks of *The Matrix* it's a miracle that anyone remembers it.

Comment: After seeing *eXistenZ*, you may never feel the same about Chinese food again.

Comment: @Praxis - It's not one to watch while eating...